# writing to file gives me NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm programming a code that writes an array of integers to a file. However, it keeps giving me a NullPointerException. Which I think is in one of two methods that I have, I know it's somewhere in there, but I can't spot it. Here's the code.

```
public static void WriteToFile (int[] n)throws IOException{
    try{
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\sortfile2.txt"));
        for(int i=0;i<=25;i++){
            bw.write(sortArray(n)+" ");
        }
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Could not write to file");
    }
}
```

This is the first method that the error could be located in. The second is here:

```
public static int sortArray(int[] a){
    int sort=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
        int max=IndexOfMaxInRange(a,i,a.length-1);
        sort=SwapElement(a,max,max++);
        a[i]=sort;
    }
    return sort;
}
```

Where `IndexOfMaxInRange` is a method that finds the highest integer of an array, and where `SwapElement` is a method that implements `IndexOfMaxInRange`, and swaps the highest number in the array, with the lowest.

Comment: Could you share the stack trace, so know line number where you getting null pointer

Comment: The exception trace should give you the exact line in which the error happens, so you don't need to guess. Can you spot that?

Comment: To get a stack trace, you need to replace `System.out.println("Could not write to file");` with `e.printStackTrace();` though.

Comment: looking at the code, I suppose in sortArray the array is null

Comment: try to use try catch while programming,it is eaiser to figure out where the error is..

Comment: do catch NullPointerException or use generic Exception to get stack trace. currently you are catching IOException

Comment: Also, you should either declare your method with `throws IOException`, saying it can throw an exception, or `catch (IOException e) { ... }` and handle the error, but not both.

Comment: you can check its length before processing like,

if(n.length > 0) {
    bw.write(sortArray(n)+" ");
}

Comment: Can you please add code for SwapElement and IndexOfMaxInRange method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,and edit according to yours(this works for me)...

```
 public static void write (String filename, int[]x) throws IOException{
      BufferedWriter outputWriter = null;
      outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
      for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        // Maybe:
        outputWriter.write(x[i]+"");
        // Or:
        outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(x[i]);
        outputWriter.newLine();
      }
      outputWriter.flush();  
      outputWriter.close();  
    }
```

Comment: Any reason why not simply do `BufferedWriter outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename));`? I didn't follow your `make sure your buffered writer was declared as null`...

Answer (score 0):

Your custom sort doesn't work and will be causing the issue. In particular

```
for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
```

means `i` becomes the last element of the array

so

```
    int max=IndexOfMaxInRange(a,i,a.length-1);
    sort=SwapElement(a,max,max++);
```

has some rather worrying index bounds issues around max, and max++ seems to be pointless.

Try it without the sorting to pinpoint your issue.